# ArcGIS Python API (gis.user.search)

Tags: arcgis-python-api, arcgis-notebook

Every time I run this code with a wild card (max_users = '*') or >140 I get this error
**JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)**. But are <140 value it works fine not just all the user are returned.

What am I doing wrong?

```
 def datetime_of_last_login(user) -> dt.datetime:
    timestamp_of_last_login = int(user.lastLogin / 1000)
    last_login = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp_of_last_login)
    return last_login

def num_days_since_last_login(user) -> int:
        last_login = datetime_of_last_login(user)
        now = dt.datetime.now()
        return (now - last_login).days
       
users = gis.users.search(query='*', max_users=140)

for user in users:
    cd = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(user.created / 1000).strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
    last_login_datetime = datetime_of_last_login(user)
    days_since_last_login = num_days_since_last_login(user)
    print("_____________________________________________________________")
    print(f"User: {user.username}")
    print(f"Role: {user.role}")
    print(f"Email: {user.email}")
    print("Creation Date:", cd)
    print("Last Login:", last_login_datetime)
    print("Days Since Last Login:", days_since_last_login)
    
    if days_since_last_login > 90:
        print (f"User:{user.username}")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was pagination. The user list is large thus there is need to pull in bit using this code

```
start = 0
lenght_searchresult = 100
while lenght_searchresult == 100:
    source_users = source.users.advanced_search(query='!esri_ & !portaladmin', start = start, max_users = 100)
    list_users = source_users.get('results')
    lenght_searchresult = len(list_users)
    start = start + 100
    for user in list_users:
        print(user.username)
```